# Switch the Odd One Out #2

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image: figure a-i and figure 1-9]

What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) is the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*created by myself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe the answer is to change the middle middle square of figure a-i and left middle square of figure 1-9. I circled these boxes with a black circle in the picture I attached. I think these boxes should be changed because the middle circles in each figure should correspond. I circled the middle middle shapes in each corresponding box. As you can see, two of the boxes do not correspond(the ones circled in red and pink) one has a x in the middle and the other has nothing.  [image]

Comment: You have found the correct figures! I am not sure about your reasoning - why the inner-most figure is more important than everything else?, but since your answer is correct I cannot disagree :)

Comment: @Plarsen I had the same reasoning. This is an inherent trouble with odd-one-out problems--there are many reasons that can be used to decide whether an item doesn't belong (and they don't always agree).

Comment: @Vitruvius True, which is the main reason why most, including this, Odd-one-out cases don't rely on the debate about what property beats another, but instead rely on the amount of properties: A size and color pattern beats a form pattern; a form, movement and color pattern beats a size and position pattern. The level of difficulty is basically how close the "next best" pattern is to the "best" pattern. It could be 5 size, 4 form and 3 rotation patterns against 5 size, 6 form and 2 rotation patterns, where the former "loses". It hardly ever exists only 1 possible pattern.

Comment: @Vitruvius The extension to the above can be a case of: color+simple movement pattern vs. color+complex rotation pattern where it will be more difficult to decide what beats the other, and the worst case scenario would be something like: color+simple movement vs. color+complex movement+complex rotation pattern. I guess no one can judge if 1 simple pattern beats two complex patterns, so such a case is in my opinion a bad design,.. or perhaps both alternatives should be considered a valid solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you

> look at the difference between the corresponding squares (assuming you do the swap given in the other answer by QuantumTwinkie,

you get

> [image]

which in my opinion is a fairly nicely-behaving pattern.

Comment: Seems to be a correct observation, but a minor detail is missing:  A diagonal line inside the circle on figure g/7.

Comment: I made the assumption that the X is actually an X on top of a \ :-)

Comment: Ah! I guess it depends on how you are viewing it :)